# More buttons are selected than the limit

Tags: jquery

Please follow these steps in the jsfiddle to understand my question

1. Click on open grid link and select option "3", buttons A,B and C would appear
2. Enter in number 2 in the number of Answers textbox. Then select buttons A and C
3. Now click on the open grid again and select option 6.
4. Now the number of Answers textbox is empty so type in 2 again in the text-box. So only 2 answers should be selected and as A and C is already selected, it should not allow another button to be selected (an alert should appear)

But this does not happen. Instead the user can select another 2 buttons and then the alert message would appear if another button is selected. This means you see 4 buttons being selected which is incorrect, it should still be 2.

So does anyone have an idea why it is doing this? It probably because the click count which somenbody mentioned is being reset everytime the grid is opened and another option is chosen.

Thanks

Code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C7vcQ/10/)

Comment: Hi, you should do, I justed tested the fiddle again and it does come with an alert. It is set as no wrap (body) and jQuery 1.7.1 in the left hand side of your fiddle?

Comment: Without wanting to read through all that code. I would guess you are reseting the click count after the "open grid" link. I would suggest you clear the selected answers after the "open grid" action. That way you dont have issue when you select number lower than the last one

Comment: sorry I forgot to get rid of some code near the bottom, javascript code has been seriously reduced, sorry about that

Comment: I dont want to clear the selected answers everytime grid is opened because lets say the user chose option 20 and chose 18 answers and then realised there should be 24 options, then if all buttons go unselected then user will have to select answers again. But actually if anyone knows how to stop resetting the click count after open grid is selected it could be the reason why it is not working

Comment: Is this like 6th time you asking people to debug the same piece of code for you? You need to learn the language/environment, learn to RTFM and debug your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this lines in the `btnclick` function:

```
if (document.getElementById("numberAnswerTxt").value == currenttotal) {
    alert('You are not allowed beyond the limit of the number of answers you require, deselect other button');
```

To this:

```
currenttotal = $('.answerBtnsOn').length;
if (int(document.getElementById("numberAnswerTxt").value) == currenttotal) {
    alert('You are not allowed beyond the limit of the number of answers you require, deselect other button');
```

Like you have done in the `insertQuestion` function, getting the number of buttons pressed by using the length of the jQuery object.

Comment: I tried your theory, thank you but it did not change the outcome, it is still causing the same problem

Comment: Try to convert the `numberAnswerTxt` value to `int` and remove the `+ 1` from the `currenttotal` variable. I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry been exercising, if I tried your second method then it does not let me select any buttons

Comment: have u tried it on fiddle as well?

Comment: figured it out, did same as your code but don't convert it to an int